# How to update value of useState in call back function

Tags: reactjs

I have a function named Login, that gets initiated on login button click. When user gets authenticated setUser sould get udpated with the email id of user, but it is not updating it and giving the previous value which is "Logged in User" in session storage. I tried useEffect but it said React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback.

```
function Login() {
    const [userIdLogin, setuserIdLogin] = useState("");
    const [passwordLogin, setpasswordLogin] = useState("");
    const [user, setuser] = useState("");

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const LoginUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!userIdLogin || !passwordLogin) {
            setErrMessage("Error.")
        } else {
            Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/login", {
                userID_Login: userIdLogin,
                password_Login: passwordLogin
            }).then((res) => {
                if (!res.data.recordsets) {
                    alert("Error")
                } else {
                    setuser(res.data.recordset[0].Email);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('Email', user) 

                    console.log(res)
                    navigate("/");
                }
            });
        };
    };

    return (
        <div id="login-box">
            
                <form onSubmit={LoginUser}>
                    <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="User Id" value={userIdLogin} onChange={(e) => {
                        setuserIdLogin(e.target.value);
                    }} />

                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={passwordLogin} onChange={(e) => {
                        setpasswordLogin(e.target.value);
                    }} />

                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />  <label style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errMessage}</label>
                </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not updating the 'user' state because when state is updated in React, it doesn't immediately take into effect. Instead, it continues executing your code as if nothing happened, and when it's done executing, your component re-renders with the updated state.

The best way to get around this is with useEffect. It takes an array of dependencies, and will listen to any changes to those dependencies, and only execute if one of the dependencies changes from the previous render.

```
function Login() {
    const [userIdLogin, setuserIdLogin] = useState("");
    const [passwordLogin, setpasswordLogin] = useState("");
    const [user, setuser] = useState("");

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const LoginUser = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!userIdLogin || !passwordLogin) {
            setErrMessage("Error.")
        } else {
            Axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/login", {
                userID_Login: userIdLogin,
                password_Login: passwordLogin
            }).then((res) => {
                if (!res.data.recordsets) {
                    alert("Error")
                } else {
                    setuser(res.data.recordset[0].Email); // User is updating
                }
            });
        };
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('Email', user) 
        console.log(res)
        navigate("/");
    }, [user]) // Dependency array, listening for user changes

    return (
        <div id="login-box">
            
                <form onSubmit={LoginUser}>
                    <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="User Id" value={userIdLogin} onChange={(e) => {
                        setuserIdLogin(e.target.value);
                    }} />

                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={passwordLogin} onChange={(e) => {
                        setpasswordLogin(e.target.value);
                    }} />

                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" />  <label style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errMessage}</label>
                </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```